# how to assign window.setTimeout to dynamic variable?

Tags: javascript

I need to assign window.setTimeout to dynamically made GLOBAL vars or objects, something like:

```
$n = 1
var variable[$n] = window.setTimeout( function () { /*somecode*/ },2000)
```

This isn't working.
Also not working:

```
var eval(variable+$n) = window.setTimeout( function () { /*somecode*/ },2000)
```

But works without "var", but I need global variable so I need with "var" scope.

What could be possible solution?

Comment: 1. what is the error? 2. if you drop the var statment and its not defined it becomes global

Comment: i think the error is that `variable` is not a array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that like this

```
variable = [];

variable[1] = window.setTimeout( function () { alert('hi') }, 2000);

// This will alert 'hi' in 2 seconds
```

or if you want to be able to call the `setTimeout` like a `function` you can do this

```
variable = [];

variable[1] = function(){ window.setTimeout( function () { alert('hi') },2000) };

// This won't alert 'hi' until you do this 

variable[1]();
```

The problem your having is that `variable` is not an `array` so if you wanted to do it your way you would have to first make `variable` an `array` like this, and global? just remove the `var`

```
$n = 1
variable = [];
variable[$n] = window.setTimeout( function () { alert('hi') },2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To address a global variable, you should not use `var`**. Using `var` redefines the variable in that scope.

Let me explain to you with a different example:

```
var i = 2; 

function show() {
   alert(i); // This will show 2
}
```

But in this example:

```
var i = 2;

function show() {
   var i = 4; //This defines a local variable called "i" to be used inside function only
   alert(i); // Will show 4;
}
alert(i); // But this will still show 2
```

So, use it without the `var`

```
$n = 1
variable[$n] = window.setTimeout( function () { /*somecode*/ },2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to reference setTimeout or execute setTimeout with code, maybe this will give you an idea:

```
window.myvar = function(){window.setTimeout( function () { alert("hi"); },2000)};
myvar();// will alert hi after 2 seconds
```

if you need to pass a variable:

```
window.myvar = function(message){
  window.setTimeout( function () { alert(message); },2000)
};
myvar("bye");// will alert bye after 2 seconds
```

setTimeout is a function and will return a number, you can use that number to cancel the timeout, the following will not alert anything because I cancel it:

```
var timeoutHandle=setTimeout(function(){alert("hi");},5000);
// next line cancels the timeout
clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
```